Is it possible to have $2$ basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$?
I was watching a video from khan academy: https://youtu.be/_uTAdf_AsfQ?si=grnYVUWzpGNDlwsx
And the video was trying to find the basis of the column space of A. In the end, $24:16$, it was found that there were $2$ basis vectors. And each vector contained $3$ elements.
The question is does this vector space belong to $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$? I would think it is a plane embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. But I'm not really sure, any guidance on this is appreciated. Thank you.

I haven't (and won't) watch the video. I think your "I think" is right.

Yes, the column space of a rank two matrix is a copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$ sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it is not literally $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It's a two dimensional  subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Every basis of $\Bbb R^3$ has exactly $3$ elements. But a basis of a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ usually has less than $3$ elements. For instance, if$$V=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\;\middle|\;x+y+z=0\right\},$$then every basis of $V$ will have $2$ elements rather than $3$. For instance, one such basis is $\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1)\}$, since

This set is linearly independent.
Every element of $V$ is a linear combination of $(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$.


Some important points first:
Matric won't form subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $P(x)$, etc., as matrix is itself a type of vector space.  There require some $\Phi$ transformations to connect matrix space with another type of vector space

Recalled:  
the definition,

a subset $A$ of a vector space B over a field $F$ is called a subspace of B if $A$ is a vector space over $F$ with the operations of addition and scalar multiplications defined on B.

and theorem, (both from Friedberg et al. Linear Algebra ed.4)

$A$ is the subspace of B

if and only if

$\forall x,y \in$ set $A$ with arbit. scalar $\lambda$,

1.$\text{ }0 \in A$ 
2.$\text{ } x+y \in A$ 
3.$\text{ } \lambda x \in A$



Consider the two following vector spaces, $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Then, for instances, 
a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be { (2,-1), (1,2) }, 
a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ would be { (1,1,0), (1,-1,-1), (1,-1,1) }.
By def. and thm. above, is there a relation between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and
$\mathbb{R}^3$ ?
Apparently no relation at all!!!
Since it's impossible to defined operation of $\mathbb{R}^3$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, vice versa. Hence, it won't fit in the def.

Now, back to your case, (after taking $\phi_\beta^{-1}$ transformation with $\beta$ is Standard Ordered Basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ ) ,
a subset {(1,2,3),(1,1,4)} is said be basis for a subspace of "?" over $F$, 

you can simply take $F$ as $\mathbb{R}$ here 

Which operating rule can be properly defined on this set?
And does it satisfy the theorem? 
I'll left these two questions to you as exercises, 
you should easily find out which vector space can have subspace generated from this set by either one question.
